# Display Product Variant Metafields

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, liquid

I need to display metafields based on the variants selected on the product page. I want them to change as the variants are clicked. I may need some jquery help but I am not that sure how to apply with liquid. Below is my code, any help is greatly appreciated!

```
{% for variant in product.variants %}
<div id="tab{{ forloop.index0 }}" class="zr-tabs-panel {% if forloop.first == true %}js-active{% endif %}">
  <div class="table-responsive>">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <tbody>
        {% for field in current_variant.metafields.var_meta %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ field | first }}</td>
          <td>{{ field | last }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Short answer is that you will need to (a): Expose your metafields to your site's javascript somehow, then (b): Update your variant-changing code to also update the section based on your metafields.

Do you happen to know where your javascript function that changes variants is?  In many themes, this is a function named `selectCallback`, though this isn't the case in all themes.  If you need help and are willing to share your site address, I should be able to find it for you just by inspecting the frontend :)

Comment: Hey thank you Dave B. I was able to find the variant-changing script and add the metafields to it. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: No worries!  Glad to be able to point you in the right direction!

Comment: Translating my comment to an answer so that you can show that this question has been solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you will need to (a): Expose your meta fields to your site's javascript somehow, then (b): Update your variant-changing code to also update the section based on your meta fields.

In many themes, the variant-changing code is contained in a function named selectCallback (though this isn't the case in all themes - if you have trouble finding this code, you can try reaching out to your theme's developer for theme-specific advice).

Whenever you're using Liquid code to put values into Javascript code, I strongly recommend using the `json` filter - Liquid's magic filter that ensures your output will always be Javascript-legal.  (Quotation marks and line breaks will be properly escaped, empty values will be printed as `null`, etc)